# Create a scheduled task with maximum privileges with schtasks

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I've been browsing the docs of `schtasks` command and I didn't find any equivalent to the checkbox "Execute with maximum privileges" (rough translation here, sorry) in the scheduled task admin windows GUI (and `/RU SYSTEM` doesn't achieve it).

Do you know if there is such an option with `schtasks`?
If so, which Windows versions can benefit from it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Rolf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find such thing because there is no such thing like maximum privileges. You must specify a user credential which has enough privileges to perform the task.

Failing to do so will cause the execution of scheduled task fail.

Here is the answer to execute the task with specified level of privileges.

https://superuser.com/questions/243605/how-do-i-specify-run-with-highest-privileges-in-schtasks

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, why does the Windows administration GUI offer such an option, then?

Comment: This is to circumvent windows features which explicitly asks for user permission to do system related changes.

Comment: And why wouldn't there be a way to achieve this with `schtasks`?

Comment: All I want is for the user to not have to check the "Execute with maximum privileges" checkbox (see scheduled tasks admin panel), I want it already checked after the scheduled task creation with `schtasks` (or any equivalent script).

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Here is your answer - http://superuser.com/questions/243605/how-do-i-specify-run-with-highest-privileges-in-schtasks

Comment: can we use that for each version of Windows (from XP to 7 or 8, including Windows Server 2008) ?

Comment: I am not sure about it, but if it is available on XP, it should be available on the later versions also.